# MSDataSetGenerator xml documentation warnings

Tags: c#, .net

I code with treat warnings as errors turned on and XML Documentation turned on. I have a Typed Dataset which generates 500+ warnings which are treated as errors. I can not control this code as it is auto generated by MSDataSetGenerator.

Is their a way to turn off warnings just for the dataset files?

Turning XML Documentation off is not an option for me as other classes are in the project.

Turning off treat warnings as errors will enable it to build. But any warnings generated by  other code in the same project will be impossible to find and will be missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/441722ys(VS.80).aspx

Of course, you would have to add the list of warnings to ignore each time the custom tool that generates the dataset's code executes...

HTH

Colby Africa

Comment: Not an options for the reason you pointed out. It is rebuilt each time the code is compiled.

Comment: How about moving your datasets into another assembly and ignore warnings from that project altogether?

Comment: I had considered moving it to its own project but was hoping for a better solution :(

Comment: There are some upsides to this.  If you are developing a system with a complex data access layer, it makes a lot of sense to decouple this from the application layers.  On the other hand, if you are developing a complex DAL, strongly typed datasets might not be the right choice...